# XPATH Use OR statement to join two different queries together so the results are in order they appear

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="bc 1000">Need this text</div>
<div class="bc 1000"><img src="https://www.test.com/png" class="and this text" alt="tick"></div>
```

I am trying to write a xpath query that grabs these two elements of text in order. So I want:

```
Need this text
and this text
```

Separately, I know the queries are:

```
//div[@class='bc 1000']

//div[@class='bc 1000']/img/@class
```

But I cannot join them together using "OR". I also don't want to use the "|" as this didn't place them in order before which is important - this is just two lines of code, there are many more.

Comment: Using `(//div[@class='bc 1000'] | //div[@class='bc 1000']/img/@class)` seems to return the matching nodes in the document order. What xpath implementation do you use?

Comment: I was using Google Chrome's xpath plugin which was showing the img/@class data beneath the other stuff. Subsequently tried another tool and it's now as I require!

Comment: Technically XPath 1.0 returns a set of nodes in no particular order. This changes in XPath 2.0 where most common expressions (such as path expressions and union expressions using "|") are guaranteed to return a sequence in document order. However, most XPath 1.0 implementations already follow this convention.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Your comment would make for a fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically XPath 1.0 returns a set of nodes in no particular order.

This changes in XPath 2.0, where most common expressions (such as path expressions and union expressions using "|") are guaranteed to return a sequence in document order.

However, most XPath 1.0 implementations already follow this convention.